# Creating Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes on Google cloud platform

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to deploy a postgres service to google cloud kubernetes with a persistent volume and persistent volume claim to provide storage for my application.

When I deploy, the pod gets stuck in a `CrashLoopBackOff`.

One of the pod's events fails with the message:

`Error: failed to start container "postgres": Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/data/postgres-pv': mkdir /data: read-only file system`

This is the yaml I am trying to deploy using kubectl:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/postgres-pv
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: postgres-pv
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-credentials
type: Opaque
data: 
  user: YWRtaW4=
  password: password==
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres-container
          image: postgres:9.6.6
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: password   
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: kubernetes_django
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-volume-mount
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-volume-mount
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

Nothing fails to deploy, but the pod gets stuck in a CrashLoopBackOff.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure, but could you try with:
`storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi`
Google persistant volumes cannot be lower than 10Gi in GCE, and I think it is the same in GKE.
Why did you not created a Google cloud SQL Postgres instance, it seems much more easier to me. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using a google cloud sql postgres instance instead

Comment: Don't hesitate if you need help, I did it few months ago :)

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: I used a Google cloud SQL postgres instance instead, as ThisIsMyName suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@markgituma/kubernetes-local-to-production-with-django-1-introduction-d73adc9ce4b4) I got it all to work with `minikube` but it gave the same error on GCP.

As mentioned by Patrick W, [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) say:

> ## Types of Persistent Volumes
>
> - ...
> - HostPath (Single node testing only – local
>     storage is not supported in any way and WILL NOT WORK in a multi-node
>     cluster)
> - ...

To solve this, I found a solution in the kubernetes [docs](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_gce.html)

You'll first have to create a `gcePersistentDisk`:

```
gcloud compute disks create --size=[SIZE] --zone=[ZONE] [DISK_NAME]
```

and then the configuration as described in the link should do the trick:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName:data-disk
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your persistent volume. You are using host path which is not, and [according to the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes), never will be, supported

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should not use host path in your persistent volume. secondly, I think you missing a part in your deployment you should specify a PDATA directory .

for the sake of simplicity I share me yml deployment :

**1. Persistance Volum Claim:**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc  
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

**2. config map to hold posgres env :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: profile
  POSTGRES_USER: postgresadmin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: othmane
  PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

**3. postgres deployment :**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
           - name: postgres-db
             mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-db
        persistentVolumeClaim: 
          claimName: postgres-pvc


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
   - protocol: "TCP"
     port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432
  type: ClusterIP
```